# Probability of a Point being 1 inch from a triangle's Centeroid?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose we choose a point uniformly from an equilateral triangle with sides of length 10 inches. What is the probability that the point will be within 1 inch of the triangle’s centroid.

---

So the the probability of this would equal the area of the centeroid divided by the area of the triangle. Would the centeroid just be a circle with a diameter of 1?

Comment: Radius, not diameter.

Comment: Don't forget that you have to confirm that a circle of 1 inch around the centroid IS completely contained within the triangle in order to just answer with that. It may be really obvious at a glance, but what if the question was with 6 inches instead?